# Is there any high-level, natively-compiled object-oriented language in wide use?

Tags: oop, native-code

There are lots of oop languages, but I couldn't find any that has conveniences like garbage collection, but compiles natively to machine code. Sort of like between C and java/c#. One interesting language I found was Vala, but that's limited to the GNOME platform and is not that well-known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Go](http://golang.org/) is probably closest.

But why on earth do you want it natively compiled anyway?

JIT compilation of portable bytecode has proved to be an extremely effective strategy. It compiles down to native code at runtime (so you get up to the performance of native code after the first few iterations) and it avoids the issues of having to build and manage platform-specific compiled binaries.

Comment: memory usage and VM/interpreter reliance could be possible reasons

Comment: @thelaststud: those were certainly possible reasons in the 1980s and early 1990s.... but on modern PC hardware it is pretty much irrelevant. Even mobiles / embedded devices can run a pretty complex VM comfortably nowadays.

Comment: I have yet to find a popular program written in go.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about C++? That is in high usage and can be compiled on nearly any (major) platform.

Comment: oh sorry, I meant "garbage collection" not "memory management"...changed it.

Comment: Is the a reasoning behind this?

Comment: more of an interest thing...I want to know whether it's possible to mix the syntactic sugar of high level languages with the performance and low memory usage of native code

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to use an oo language that compiles down to native code you will "always" have to use header files and stuff as the elf format doesn't support oo (There is no class information in elf).In case you want to use classes from external libs you need to make the compiler aware somehow about the fact that there are classes, functions, etc. that are declared outside of your project. In C++ this is solved by the use of header files. So that's, I think, a major drawback in native object oriented languages. To resolve that issue a few tweaks would need to be made to elf/loader/linker in order to support the kind of features (like "linking" against "classes") you might expect. Even though mechanism for garbage collection could be implemented even in native languages. But that seems no good for os implementation.

There are C++ libs to do that for userspace apps like:
[Boehm collector](http://hboehm.info/gc/)
[Smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)